# Cannot replace LSTMBlockCell with LSTMBlockFusedCell in Python TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Replacing [`LSTMBlockCell`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/LSTMBlockCell) with [`LSTMBlockFusedCell`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/LSTMBlockFusedCell) throws a TypeError in static_rnn`. I'm using TensorFlow 1.2.0-rc1 compiled from source.

The full error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-2986e054cb6b> in <module>()
     19     enc_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMBlockFusedCell(rnn_size)
     20     enc_layers = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([enc_cell] * num_layers, state_is_tuple=True)
---> 21     _, enc_state = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(enc_layers, enc_input_unstacked, dtype=dtype)
     22 
     23 with tf.variable_scope('decoder'):

~/Virtualenvs/scikit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py in static_rnn(cell, inputs, initial_state, dtype, sequence_length, scope)
   1139 
   1140   if not _like_rnncell(cell):
-> 1141     raise TypeError("cell must be an instance of RNNCell")
   1142   if not nest.is_sequence(inputs):
   1143     raise TypeError("inputs must be a sequence")

TypeError: cell must be an instance of RNNCell
```

Code to reproduce:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

batch_size = 8
enc_input_length = 1000

dtype = tf.float32
rnn_size = 8
num_layers = 2

enc_input = tf.placeholder(dtype, shape=[batch_size, enc_input_length, 1])
enc_input_unstacked = tf.unstack(enc_input, axis=1)

with tf.variable_scope('encoder'):
    enc_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMBlockFusedCell(rnn_size)
    enc_layers = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([enc_cell] * num_layers)
    _, enc_state = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(enc_layers, enc_input_unstacked, dtype=dtype)
```

`_like_rnncell` looks like:

```py
def _like_rnncell(cell):
  """Checks that a given object is an RNNCell by using duck typing."""
  conditions = [hasattr(cell, "output_size"), hasattr(cell, "state_size"),
                hasattr(cell, "zero_state"), callable(cell)]
  return all(conditions)
```

Turns out `LSTMBlockFusedCell` doesn't have the `output_size` and `state_size` properties that `LSTMBlockCell` implements.

Is this a bug, or is there a way to use `LSTMBlockFusedCell` that I'm missing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`LSTMBlockFusedCell` is inherited from `FusedRNNCell` instead of `RNNCell`, so you cannot use standard `tf.nn.static_rnn` or `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` in which they require `RNNCell` instance (as shown in your error message).

However, in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/LSTMBlockFusedCell), you can directly call the cell to get the complete outputs and state.

```
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [time_len, batch_size, input_size])
fused_rnn_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMBlockFusedCell(num_units)

outputs, state = fused_rnn_cell(inputs, dtype=tf.float32)

# outputs shape is (time_len, batch_size, num_units)
# state: LSTMStateTuple where c shape is (batch_size, num_units)
#  and h shape is also (batch_size, num_units).
```

The `LSTMBlockFusedCell` object calls `gen_lstm_ops.block_lstm` [internally](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/lstm_ops.py#L657), which should be equivalent to a normal LSTM loop.

Also, notice that the inputs to any `FusedRNNCell` instance should be time-major, this can be done by just transposing the tensor before calling the cell.