# Using tensorflow DropoutWrapper with LSTMBlockFusedCell

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to use DropoutWrapper  with LSTMBlockFusedCell as follows:

```
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMBlockFusedCell(num_units,forget_bias)
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell,dropout)
```

I get an exception that the LSTMBlockFusedCell is not an RNNCell

Message: The parameter cell is not a RNNCell. Which is raised form _like_rnncell during DropoutWrapper initialization.

It is checking for those proprieties on the cell:

```
""Checks that a given object is an RNNCell by using duck typing."""

  conditions = [hasattr(cell, "output_size"), hasattr(cell, "state_size"),
                hasattr(cell, "zero_state"), callable(cell)]
```

LSTMBlockFusedCell  does not have output_size , state_size or zero_state properties.

I wonder whether this is a bug or is their any other reason for not handling  LSTMBlockFusedCell   as an RNNCell.

Comment: Another related issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44521970/cannot-replace-lstmblockcell-with-lstmblockfusedcell-in-python-tensorflow/46714727#46714727

Answer (score 0):

I opened an issue for tensorflow, it seems to be a bug. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13649

Answer (score 0):

The [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13649) suggested using `tf.nn.dropout` on inputs as a workaround and they didn't plan to implement the dropout in `LSTMBlockFusedCell` or fix the `DropoutWrapper` at the time. But I think `tf.layers.dropout` may be easier to use since it provides the `training` argument.